# Moving a node and it's related siblings into a new parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm attempting copy an element and it's related siblings (where they exist in such an order) into a new shared parent but I'm struggling to do this - my XSLT knowledge is limited.

Given the following XML (which can be considered HTML):

```
<root>
    <p />
    <p />
    <heading />
    <content />
    <image />
    <p />
    <p />
    <heading />
    <p />
    <p />
    <image />
    <p />
    <p />
    <heading />
    <content />
    <image />
    <p />
    <p />
    <p />
</root>
```

I am attempting to create this structure:

```
<root>
    <p />
    <p />
    <wrapper>
        <heading />
        <content />
        <image />
    </wrapper>
    <p />
    <p />
    <heading />
    <p />
    <p />
    <image />
    <p />
    <p />
    <wrapper>
        <heading />
        <content />
        <image />
    </wrapper>
    <p />
    <p />
    <p />
</root>
```

This is the start of my stylesheet, first copying each node into the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//heading[following-sibling::content][following-sibling::image]">
    </xsl:stylesheet>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But after this I'm unsure (conceptually) how to handle the next stage. I need to move each set of `<heading />`, `<content />` and `<image />` nodes into a new element.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to move each set of `<heading />, <content /> and <image />`
>   nodes into a new element.

Would something like this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="heading[following-sibling::*[1][self::content] and following-sibling::*[2][self::image]]">
    <wrapper>
        <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::*[1] | following-sibling::*[2]"/>
    </wrapper>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::heading] and following-sibling::*[1][self::image]]"/>
<xsl:template match="image[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::content] and preceding-sibling::*[2][self::heading]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this does what I need to do. I found it easier to understand your code written as `heading[following-sibling::content[1]` rather than `heading[following-sibling::*[1][self::content]`. Being new to this I can say they _appear_ to have the same effect. Is this correct?

Comment: "*they appear to have the same effect. Is this correct?*" No it is not. Your version selects a `heading` that has ***some*** following-sibling named `content`; my version selects a `heading` whose ***immediately*** following sibling is `content`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, I think I get it now.